# How do I create a function that reads and plays my array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In my app a user can choose to store their input into an array for eg.

```
"[{"time":1835,"elemId":"bass"},{"time":2553,"elemId":"highhat"}]"
```

This is well and good apart from when I'm trying to replay their input using the example information above.

I think the trouble is I'm using a plugin called LowLatencyAudio which is installed via phonegap which makes things a bit complicated for me.

So instead of trying to 'mimic' the user's input I'd rather just play the .mp3 files that are attached to each button.

This is the code I'm using at the moment with no avail

```
document.getElementById('playback').onclick = function () {
console.log(localStorage.getItem("eventlist"));
var playback = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("eventlist"))


for (i = 0; i < playback.length; i++) {
    play = playback[i];
    setTimeout((function (play) {
        return function () {
            lla.play();
        }
    })(play), play.time)
}
}
```

Which returns the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'play' of undefined.
```

I'll put in the button and the function I'm trying to call for good measure but I just can't seem to find a result, any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Button

```
<div class="drum" id="bass" ontouchstart="play('bass');" ontouchend="touchEnd(event);">Bass</div>
```

Play function

```
function play(drum) {
            document.getElementById(drum).className = 'drum touched';
            lla.play('assets/' + drum + '.mp3');
        }
```

Comment: what's and where is `lla` defined?

Comment: I think it must be defined in the docs found here.
[link]https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-lowlatencyaudio

Comment: well, your instance of lla, is it really instantiated when you invoke the play method?

Comment: and/or is it within the scope of your lambda?